# How to load stream cin into vector

Tags: c++

I want to load a vector with integers from cin. The following code works:

```
std::istream_iterator< int > iterBegin( std::cin ), iterEnd;
vector< int > v( iterBegin, iterEnd );
```

However, when I try to write it more succinctly, it fails:

```
vector< int > v(std::istream_iterator< int >(std::cin), 
                std::istream_iterator< int >() );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The second example looks like a function declaration, declaring a function `v` taking two parameters of types `std::istream_iterator< int >` and `std::istream_iterator< int >()`, and returning a `vector< int >`. It would work if you use braces instead: `vector< int > v{...}` [Demo](http://rextester.com/LQA8993)

Comment: Please post the compile error message. It works for me. http://ideone.com/6dNtji.

Comment: @RSahu: It compiles, but doesn't do anything, other than declare a function which is never used or defined.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I assumed the OP was having trouble compiling code. I might've been mistaken.

Comment: He probably is having trouble compiling it when he tries to use `v` as if it is a vector.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Perfect thank you! Yes are using [uniform initialization syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse#Uniform_initialization_syntax).

Comment: Yes you guys are right, it compiles fine but I get errors when I try to use it as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As IgorTandetnik pointed out, you ran into C++'s Most vexing parse. The solution (if your compiler understands C++11) is to use uniform initialization syntax.

clang has a suggestion that will work even in C++98:

```
cin-vec.cc:7:21: warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
std::vector< int > v(std::istream_iterator< int >(std::cin),
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cin-vec.cc:7:22: note: add a pair of parentheses to declare a variable
std::vector< int > v(std::istream_iterator< int >(std::cin),
                     ^
                     (                                     )
cin-vec.cc:12:19: error: member reference base type 'std::vector<int> (std::istream_iterator<int>, std::istream_iterator<int> (*)())' is not a structure or union
    std::cout << v.size();
                 ~^~~~~
```

i.e. change your code to:

```
std::vector< int > v((std::istream_iterator< int >(std::cin)),
                std::istream_iterator< int >() );
```